# Merge dataframes without duplicate rows with NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, join, outer-join

I have data from multiple files that have data hourly observations for different variables. I'm trying to combine them to a single dataframe where I have every observation for each variable for the whole time interval. Some variables have data in multiple dataframes for different time intervals. Each dataframe has a time column that can be used for joining.

The problem is that `full_join` creates more rows than my data has hours (`df1`). Instead I would like to get a dataframe (`df2`) without `NA` values and extra rows. One solution is to join the dataframes in specific order but I'm hoping for a more general solution that works with larger scale for combining datasets for this type of data.

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- data.frame(hour = 1:10, x = 5)
b <- data.frame(hour = 1:15, y = 15)
c <- data.frame(hour = 11:20, x = 10)

list <- list(a,b,c)

df1 <- list %>%
  reduce(full_join)

df1
   hour  x  y
1     1  5 15
2     2  5 15
3     3  5 15
4     4  5 15
5     5  5 15
6     6  5 15
7     7  5 15
8     8  5 15
9     9  5 15
10   10  5 15
11   11 NA 15
12   12 NA 15
13   13 NA 15
14   14 NA 15
15   15 NA 15
16   11 10 NA
17   12 10 NA
18   13 10 NA
19   14 10 NA
20   15 10 NA
21   16 10 NA
22   17 10 NA
23   18 10 NA
24   19 10 NA
25   20 10 NA

df2 <- full_join(a,c) %>%
  full_join(b)

df2
   hour  x  y
1     1  5 15
2     2  5 15
3     3  5 15
4     4  5 15
5     5  5 15
6     6  5 15
7     7  5 15
8     8  5 15
9     9  5 15
10   10  5 15
11   11 10 15
12   12 10 15
13   13 10 15
14   14 10 15
15   15 10 15
16   16 10 NA
17   17 10 NA
18   18 10 NA
19   19 10 NA
20   20 10 NA
```

EDIT:
I got the correct result with tidyverse with following code:

```
df <- list %>%
  reduce(full_join) %>%
  group_by(hour) %>%
  summarise_all(mean, na.rm = T)
```

With data.table `melt`and `dcast` also seem to work

```
dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)
m <- as.data.table(melt(dt1, id.vars = "hour"))
dc <- dcast.data.table(m, hour~variable, fun.aggregate = mean, na.rm = T)
df <- as.data.frame(dc)
```

I guess `mean` can be replaced with some other function but I couldn't figure which.

Comment: How is the join supposed to handle the case where `b` contains also information of `x`? For example `b <- data.frame(hour = 1:15, x = 15, y = 15)`. In this case you would have multiple values for `x` on `hour %in% 1:10`. This is relevant for a general approach for this I guess.

Comment: Either way, perhaps you have to left join all information onto a new created dataset that just contains all hours? `library(magrittr); lapply(list,extract2,"hour") %>% unlist %>% unique`

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. But--Please don't edit a question in a way that invalidates reasonable posted answers.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version where the primary key can be a composite (for example `hour` and `group`). It doesn't work with aggregating like your own solution you added to the question.

```
## Identify (composite) primary key 
mykeys <- c("hour")

## Using the data.table package below
list %>%
    lapply(setDT)

## Create a dataset with all unique combinations of the keys to join onto
full <- lapply(list, function(dt) dt[,..mykeys]) %>%
    rbindlist %>%
    unique

## Can make the keys as actual keys on the full dataset but not necessary
# setkeyv(full,mykeys)

## Join all variables onto the full dataset.
## The preserved values of duplicates are from the last dataset in the order of 
## the list object. This step is done by reference.
list %>%
    lapply(function(dt) {
        n <- names(dt)
        full[dt,
             on = mykeys,
             (n) := mget(paste0("i.", n))]
    })
full
```

Here is an example dataset with a composite primary key and more columns to help identify what is going on. Again, note that the order of the datasets in `list` matter.

```
mykeys <- c("hour"
            ,"group"
)

a <- data.frame(hour = 1:10, 
                group = 1,
                x = 5, z = 1, a = 1)
b <- data.frame(hour = 1:15, 
                group = 1,
                y = 15, z = 2, b = 1)
c <- data.frame(hour = 11:20, 
                group = 1,
                # group = 2,
                x = 10, z = 3, c = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to specify the `by` keyword in join.
Here is a solution using `coalesce_join` from [E. Visel blog post](https://alistaire.rbind.io/blog/coalescing-joins/). I slightly modified it to use `coalesce` only in the case when there are common columns in the two dataframes to join, otherwise it fails because the `coalesced` dataframe is empty.

```r
library(tidyverse)

a <- data.frame(hour = 1:10, x = 5)
b <- data.frame(hour = 1:15, y = 15)
c <- data.frame(hour = 11:20, x = 10)

l <- list(a,b,c)

coalesce_join <- function(x, y, 
                              by = NULL, suffix = c(".x", ".y"), 
                              join = dplyr::full_join, ...) {
        joined <- join(x, y, by = by, suffix = suffix, ...)
        # names of desired output
        cols <- union(names(x), names(y))
        common_cols <- setdiff(intersect(names(x), names(y)), by)
        if(length(common_cols) > 0) {
          # if there are common columns, we need to coalesce them
          to_coalesce <- names(joined)[!names(joined) %in% cols]
          suffix_used <- suffix[ifelse(endsWith(to_coalesce, suffix[1]), 1, 2)]
          # remove suffixes and deduplicate
          to_coalesce <- unique(substr(
              to_coalesce, 
              1, 
              nchar(to_coalesce) - nchar(suffix_used)
          ))
          
          coalesced <- purrr::map_dfc(to_coalesce, ~dplyr::coalesce(
              joined[[paste0(.x, suffix[1])]], 
              joined[[paste0(.x, suffix[2])]]
          ))
          names(coalesced) <- to_coalesce

          joined <- dplyr::bind_cols(joined, coalesced)[cols]
      }
      return(joined)
}

reduce(l, coalesce_join, by="hour")
```

This snippet gives me the desired output without caring for the column names.

NB: According to the documentation, `coalesce` finds the first non-missing element, so you have to be aware of this behaviour if there are overlapping values of `x` in several dataframes.

---

NB: I renamed `l` to be your `list` object.
I believe it is not good for code clarity to overload language-specific keywords.

Comment: Finally, there are already [plenty of StackO threads about joining dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I should add that I would like to get a single x column (indentical to df2) instead of x.x and x.y columns as the x is the same variable in both dataframes (just different time interval).

Comment: A note to your reassign comment: the function `list` is not reassigned here, it is just overloaded. `append(list,list(d,e))` still works like expected. `list <- function() {...}` would be a reassign.

Comment: I edited my post, `coalesce` looks like the right function to use here. The solution is not yet fully automated, as you have to specify column names in `mutate`. Googling around, E. Visel proposes [in a blog post](https://alistaire.rbind.io/blog/coalescing-joins/) the `coalesce_join` function. This might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried group_by and summarise_all with na.omit which removes some rows. `df1 <- list %>%
  reduce(full_join) %>%
  group_by(hour) %>%
  summarise_all(na.omit)`
I will try coalesce next but I would like a solution where I don't have to name the columns that have to be combined.

Comment: OK, from the blog post mentioned above I managed to obtain something that works in your case without naming the columns. I edited my answer.

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Frequently-duplicate questions should be closed, not answered.